# Jenkins gerrit trigger not fetching my change when building

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I have configured jenkins with gerrit trigger plugin to validate every commit we review to gerrit. I am expecting this trigger to include my latest change with original repo and make a build. But, it is cloning only repo project and compiling without my change.
Below is my configuration settings for gerrit trigger in jenkins.

```
Refspec: $GERRIT_REFSPEC 
Branches to build: $GERRIT_BRANCH 
Build trigger: Gerrit event 
Trigger on: patch set created 
Gerrit project: added project and branch
```

Comment: Is the value of `GERRIT_REFSPEC` the same with your change's ref? It's something like `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1`.

Answer (score 6):

Refspec: $GERRIT_REFSPEC point to refs/changes/XX/XXXXX/X

If you want get code from gerrit，you should execute this cmd in your Build step：

```
git fetch $GIT_URL $GERRIT_REFSPEC && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

---

OR you can try this:

> https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

To get the Git Plugin to download your change;

1. set Refspec to $GERRIT_REFSPEC
2. set 'Branches to build' to $GERRIT_BRANCH.

If this does not work for you

1. set Refspec to refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
2. set 'Branches to build' to $GERRIT_REFSPEC.

Answer (score 4):

Change the following itens of your job configuration.

From:

```
Refspec: $GERRIT_REFSPEC 
Branches to build: $GERRIT_BRANCH
```

To:

```
Refspec: $GERRIT_REFSPEC:$GERRIT_REFSPEC 
Branches to build: $GERRIT_REFSPEC
```

Consider to add "Draft Published" to the "Trigger on" option.